# my custom viewcontroller delegate not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, storyboard

I am trying to send a simple string from One viewcontroller to another viewcontroller using delegate but my delegate is not working. I am using storyboard and dont want to use segue to pass data. Here is my simple code

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewControllerA;

@protocol viewControllerADelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item;

@end

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController{
 __weak id <viewControllerADelegate> delegate;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (weak) id<viewControllerADelegate> delegate;
@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerA ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize delegate;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.delegate addItem:self data:@"this is data"];

 }
 @end
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController<viewControllerADelegate>

@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

ViewControllerA *vca = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
[vca setDelegate:self];

 }

- (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item{
NSLog(@"delegate function called");
 }

 @end
```

Am I missing something silly ? The delegate method `-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item` is not triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw in your design is to try sending data with delegates to an object you create yourself. You certainly don't need delegates for that as you can do it with simple properties. `myViewControllerBObject.dataProperty = @"some data"];` is simply enough. What delegation is usually used for is send data back to the controller that created the current object or to any other controller somewhere in your app.

For example, move the delegate code in `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB` and add a `UIButton` and an `IBAction` to `ViewControllerB` that will send the data **back** to `ViewControllerA`. Here it goes:

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewControllerB;

@protocol viewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) sendDataBack: (ViewControllerB *)controller data:(NSString *)item;

@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
{
   __unsafe_unretained id <viewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<viewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)buttonTouch:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB
@synthesize delegate;
....
- (IBAction)buttonTouch:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate sendDataBack:self data:@"my data"];
}
@end
```

And in `ViewControllerA`, you first need to get a hold of that pushed `ViewControllerB` object via segues. Then implement the delegate method.

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <viewControllerBDelegate>
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerA ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
......
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"id %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
    ViewControllerB *vcb = (ViewControllerB *)[segue destinationViewController];
    vcb.delegate = self;  //key point
}
- (void)sendDataBack:(ViewControllerB *)controller data:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"Here is the data %@ and the controller it comes from %@", item, controller);
}
@end
```

Hope this will help you get a better understanding of communication with delegates.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.But I am confused How to send data between tab bars using delegates as they dont have segues ? such as sending data from a second tab to first tab backward ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's another question and I believe it requires a separate post. Nevertheless, that's almost the same as this and easy to understand as well. If the answer I posted solves the problem you had here, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: Here I have posted the question about tab bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133934/passing-data-between-tabs-using-delegate-not-working
I would be grateful to you if you solve the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the delegate variable (strong, nonatomic) instead of (__weak).

Comment: made it @property (strong,nonatomic) id<viewControllerADelegate> delegate
But no result :(