# iOS Protocol / Delegate confusion?

Tags: ios, objective-c

All this is my first post and I will try to be as precise as possible. I have read numerous articles about protocol / delegate implementation for iOS but all examples failed.
Let say 
I have A and B controller and want to send data from A to B.
A.h

```
    @protocol exampleprot <NSObject>
@required
-(void) exampledmethod:(NSString *) e1;
@end

@interface ViewController
{
__weak id <exampleprot> delegate
}
```

--
A.m
in some procedure
I try to push

```
[delegate  examplemethod:@"test"]
```

---

B.h

```
@interface test2 : UiViewcontroller <exampleprot>
```

and in B.m implement method -(void) exampledmethod:(NSString *) e1;

---

so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what your tring to do ...?

Comment: Are you assigning the delegate? Like `objectOfA.delegate = objectOfB`? If not a property, any other way?

Comment: i want to send data from A to B (passing strings via example method) controllers via protocol/delegate, but I am missing some steps, and after reading a lot of o articles on net, i could NOT understand what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically this is the example of custom delegates and it is used for sending messages from one class to another. So for sending message in another class you need to first set the delegate and then conforming the protocol in another class as well. Below is the example:-

`B.h` class

```
@protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(NSString *)getDataValue;
@end
@interface BWindowController : NSWindowController
{
    id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

In `B.m` class

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
 //below only calling the method but it is impelmented in AwindowController class
   if([[self delegate]respondsToSelector:@selector(getDataValue)]){
    NSString *str= [[self delegate]getDataValue];
     NSLog(@"Recieved=%@",str);
    }
    [super windowDidLoad];
}
```

In `A.h` class

```
@interface AWindowController : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate> //conforming to the protocol
```

In `A.m` class

```
 //Implementing the protocol method 
    -(NSString*)getDataValue
    {
        NSLog(@"recieved");
        return @"recieved";
    }
//In this method setting delegate AWindowController to BWindowController
    -(void)yourmethod
    {

    BWindowController *b=[[BWindowController alloc]init];
    b.delegate=self;   //here setting the delegate 

    }
```

Comment: Your explanation is very good, i mixed where to put protocol, if sending A to B- then protocol should be in B - thanks for that, othe thing, I tryed your example, but Receive=null still?

Comment: Can you show me your code?? In which you are setting the delegate??

Comment: I am adding it in viewDidLoad of A.m

Comment: Set in your action method or other method inspite of setting in load method,

Comment: I tryed, but it is the same, always NULL? what you suggest?

Comment: getDataValue in A.m is never called (maybe because it should be in B.m)?

Comment: In B.m class in which method you are calling getDataValue??

Comment: in viewdidLoad and tryed in viewdid appear, still same, -the calling is like from your example -  NSString *str= [[self delegate]getDataValue];
     NSLog(@"Recieved=%@",str); and result is NULL?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, you are telling me that with custom delegate is not good for communication between two controllers? OR I misunderstood?

Comment: sorry please ignore my previous comments and also please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115913/my-custom-viewcontroller-delegate-not-working. In this link here is the example of two viewcontroller

Comment: heh, well the error was recreating NEW viewcontrol, and since i was using existing,had just to point it to it, anyway +1 from me

Comment: In class `B.h` apple uses nonatomic instead of readwrite. Although this is just a minor difference. `@property(readwrite,assign)id<sampleDelegate>delegate;` Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from A to B, then you should define a delegate in B with return type.    In B, there will be delegate declaration:

```
@protocol example <NSObject>
@required
-(NSString *) exampleMethod;
@end
```

Then in A, implement this method. In A.m, you need to have

```
-(NSString *) exampleMethod:(NSString *) e1 {
    // Implementation of this delegate method
    return self.stringYouWantToPassToB
}
```

Then in B, all you need to do is use that delegate to get what you want from A. In B.m, you have

```
- (void)methodInB {
    // Get string from delegate
    self.string = [self.delegate exampleMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate property of the view controller from where you want to send the data = the view controller to where you want to send the data. I think Hussain's answer is correct. You just need to check if you are doing it the correct way.