# Passing data into an object using properties in Obj.C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm having a hard time understanding how parents and children communicate (and how they pass data to each-other). I have two simple objects (two ViewControllers). I understand that the parent-child relationship should allow me to pass two variables from the child object into the parent object using properties. Since I included Obj. B into Obj A I assume that A is the parent and B is the child. I also understand that the child knows about the parent but not vice-versa, is that correct?

I included Obj. B into Obj. A and I was hoping to have access to a few variables I have declared in the header file of Obj. B

Could somebody give me a very simple example and help me put an end to my confusion? Thanks much.

Comment: To pass data from A to B you can easily use `property`. To access data from B to A you can have a look to `protocol`.

Tell us if you use storyboard or not also for pass data using property

Comment: What do you mean by "parent-child relationship"?

Comment: @JordanMontel, for now I'm just trying to pass two variables from A to B. I understand that from B to A I would need to use protocols. But I'm having a hard understanding who needs the properties. Is B able to access the properties of A or vice-versa?

Comment: @Nactus I have a feeling that you confuse classes with instances...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, what I mean by "parent-child" relationship is that one obj. inherits from the other (or has access to its properties and methods) - at least that's what I understand.

Comment: @Nactus Exactly what I thought... Class inheritance has little to nothing to do with assignment of properties.

Comment: @H2CO3 could you help me understand the difference?

Comment: @Nactus Well... it's hard to explain in one comment. A class is sort of a template. The implementation of a class tells you how a particular instance of the class (an object) will behave **once the class is instantiated** (i. e. an object is created). -- Objects can have properties. Properties belong to a certain object. Different objects of the same class can have their properties set to completely different values. That doesn't at all depend on the class of the object.

Comment: @Nactus you want an example to pass data from viewControllerA to viewControllerB using storyboard ?

Comment: @Nactus class inheritance is like saying I have a class called Shape and then a class called Square that inherits from shape. The Square class will inherit all the methods and properties that the Shape class has. Now Instances or Ownership is like having a Car object that then owns 4 Tire objects. Tires do not inherit from the Car class. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Hackmodford I think it does. So, in order to make one class inherit from another we #include them into others, therefore creating a parent-child relationship..? Is that right ? Now I'm starting to see the difference between a class and an instance of an object (of a specific class). I also understand the idea of setting getters and setters for certain properties to be able to be accessed from "outside".

Comment: @JordanMontel, just basic setters and getters from one object to the other. I suppose that later, when passing variables from A to B to C, since I understand that in Obj C there is no "multi-inheritance" I will try to see how a singleton object works.I"m not using storyboards; just xib files

Comment: ok @Nactus, I add an answer to show you how to pass data from viewControllerA to viewControllerB using XIB and property

Comment: @Nactus No inheritance would be declared like this "@interface Square : Shape" the Square object will inherit all the methods and properties that a Shape object has. If there is a way to start a chat I can explain this better for you if you'd like.

Comment: @Hackmodford, thanks. What's the best way to start a chat? It would be great if we could chat about this. Is it ok (based on stackoverflow's policy) to interchange IM's information? Or I should is a PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data (object or value) forward to a `ViewControllerB` from a `ViewControllerA` pushing or presenting ViewControllers, you need to do something like this :

(for example, pass a NSString to a `ViewControllerB` from a `ViewControllerA`)

**Passing data forward without Storyboard :**

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.aString = myString; // myString is the data you want to pass
[self presentViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Using `UINavigationController` :

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.aString = myString;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

and inside `viewControllerB`, you need to have a `@property` on your .h like :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
```

and inside your .m, you retrieve this `@property` :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"%@", _aString);
}
```

This is an example with a NSString, but you can pass any object.

Comment: Thank you Jordan, upvoted. All answers are informative, but I was looking for something like this, so I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it backwards. The the parent IS supposed to know about the child. The child should not need to know about its parent.

The parent can have a strong reference to its child. (ex)

```
//inside the parent class
@property (nonatomic, strong) id childObject;
```

The child commonly will not know explicitly what its "Parent" is, but it will have a weak reference to a delegate. That delegate can either be a specific type of class, or a generic class of type `id` that conforms to a particular protocol. (ex)

```
//inside the child class
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeProtocol> delegate;
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, upvoted. So the delegat would be use to pass data back from the child to the parent, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up circular references using weak assignment in one of the objects:

ObjectA.h

```
@class ObjectB
@interface ObjectA
@property (strong) ObjectB *parent;
@end
```

ObjectA.m

```
#import "ObjectA.h"
#import "ObjectB.h"
@implementation ObjectA
// methods
@end
```

ObjectB.h

```
@class ObjectA
@interface ObjectB
@property (weak) ObjectA *child;
@end
```

ObjectB.m

```
#import "ObjectB.h"
#import "ObjectA.h"
@implementation ObjectB
// methods
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom delegate and send messages from one class to another. So that the behavior will be one class will be sender and other will be reciever. For reference follow this:-

[iOS Protocol / Delegate confusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679216/ios-protocol-delegate-confusion/19679547#19679547)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good programming style but you could use singleton to share data between many different classes

Like that:
Singleton.h

```
@interface Settings : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *mySharedString;
+ (Settings *)my;
- (id)init;
@end
```

Singleton.m

```
#import "Settings.h"
@implementation Settings
@synthesize mySharedString
static Settings *my = nil;
+ (Settings *)my
{
  if (!my)
    my = [Settings new];
  return my;
}

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self){
     //do some code
   }
   return self
}
@end
```

And then in any class you can say something like

```
NSString *classString = [Settings my].mySharedString
```

Comment: Thanks for the singleton design pattern. I am kind of trying to use setter and getters at this point (trying to learn how to walk before I run) :D

Comment: in this case (if you have property of NSMutableString) you can use
`[Settings my].mySharedString = @"some text"` 
to call setter and
`NSString *myText = [Settings my].mySharedString`
to call getter

Answer (score 0):

You are in charge of passing data between view controller. You can use `-parentViewController` or `-childViewControllers`, you also can make circular references using `weak` references.

If you are using storyboard maybe it will be a good idea to take a look at `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. Sender can be used to pass data between view controller.

Also if you are using storyboard, sometimes `- instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` is handy thing.

There is more than one way to  do that.