# Data source delegate in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm trying to implement data source delegate in cell (to get `filters` array from TableViewController):

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<SLFilterCellDelegate>)delegate{
    NSAssert(self.delegate, @"");
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getSLFilters)]) {
        self.filters = [self.delegate getSLFilters];
        self.names = [self.filters valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"self.names: %@", [self.names description]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `delegate` is `nil`.

In my TableViewController I do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SLFilterCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Why delegate is nil? What is the right place to ask delegate for data?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679216/ios-protocol-delegate-confusion/19679547#19679547

Comment: In "setDelegate" API, before accessing the delegate, set:

_delegate = delegate;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `setDelegate:` and not actually setting the delegate, which is why it remains nil. If you override a property setter like that, you probably want to start it with `_delegate = delegate` to actually assign the underlying instance variable. Then `self.delegate` will no longer be nil. So:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<SLFilterCellDelegate>)delegate{
    _delegate = delegate;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getSLFilters)]) {
        self.filters = [self.delegate getSLFilters];
        self.names = [self.filters valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"self.names: %@", [self.names description]);
    }
}
```