# What is the point in having protocols if they are not checked?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, protocols, nstableview

I'm going through the book about Cocoa and Objective C ("Aaron Hillegass, Adam Preble - Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X - 2012") and when I did the example with NSTableView, I noticed that it really doesn't matter if I define my class as conforming to `NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate` protocols or omit them, only methods matter. (looks like sort of *duck typing*)

That is, the application works fine with both definitions:

`@interface SpeakLineAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>`
and
`@interface SpeakLineAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>`

It only yells at me *at runtime* if I don't implement 2 essential methods which are defined in `NSTableViewDataSource`, and in any case it doesn't matter at all if I put these protocols in class definition or not. So, what is the point in having them in the language? If they are only for documentation, we could put their names in comments as well, right? Or I'm missing something important here?

Comment: If the methods are `@required`, you should be warned at compile time.

Comment: @jtbandes But if a protocol has only optional methods, it's useless?

Comment: objective-c is a language strongly driven by convention, you can do a lot of things you shouldn't be able too, but people that maintain your code are not going to be happy with you.

Comment: Do you hook up the data source and delegate in a xib or in code?

Comment: If you try to set the delegate or data source to an object that doesn't declare conformance, you will have mismatched types and should get a compiler warning. `id<NSTableViewDelegate>` is not equal to `id`.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679216/ios-protocol-delegate-confusion/19679547#19679547

Comment: Even if a method is `@optional`, this still hints the IDE where to go if you ⌘-click on something, and it lets you call e.g. `[delegate doSomething]` without casting first (although if it's optional you should check `-respondsToSelector:` first).

Comment: @robmayoff This time I did it in Interface Builder (to minimize chance of getting lost; making sure everything in the example works as expected before starting to experiment is important for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol conformance can be checked at compile-time and runtime. Like most people said in the comments, protocol conformance is checked at compile-time. If you assign a type that doesn't conform to the protocol (other than `id`) to a variable of type bracketed with that protocol, the compiler should give you a warning. So in order to be able to pass an object that doesn't conform to a protocol to a parameter of that parameter type, you must have either 1) ignored a warning, or 2) gone through type `id`, which turns off static type checking.

The API you call also *could* (if it wanted to) check at runtime whether your objects formally conform to the protocol or not, using `conformsToProtocol:`. However, the convention in Cocoa is that the APIs never check for formal conformance to the protocol, but rather only check that it responds to a given selector when it needs to call it. This gives more flexibility to the user to, for example, use a class object (metaclasses can't formally conform to protocols, other than the ones conformed to by the root class) as a delegate.